# Serve S3 ressources via https

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3, lets-encrypt

I'm running into an issue while trying to serve files from an AWS s3 bucket with a custom domain name via https.

What I have today :

- A s3 bucket with, sub.domain.com.s3-xxxxxxx.com access url
- A DNS set to redirect sub.domain.com to the IP of one of my ec2 instances.
- The above mentionned ec2 instance with a docker container running my NGINX configuration.
- certbot installed on the same instance.

What I am trying to do:

- Redirect https://sub.domain.com to https://sub.domain.com.s3-xxxxxxx.com

Where I am stucked:

- Certbot won't generate ssl certificates for sub.domain.com.

I tried to redirect all request to sub.domain.com to my existing website running on the instance with NGINX.
The idea was to generate the certificates and then use it for redirection to my bucket, since certbot can't create .well-known/acme-challenges in a s3 bucket.

Even that won't work. I'm kind of stuck here. All I need is to generate certificate with let's encrypt in order to let my custom domain name redirect to https. Obviously I'll need to renew it later but I guess it won't be an issue once the certificate will be effectively created.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Forgot to post the error, here it is (replaced my domain name with the example):

```
Failed authorization procedure. sub.domain.com (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://sub.domain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/xxxxx
```

And my nginx conf :

```
server {
     listen 80;
     server_name sub.domain.com;
     rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
     client_max_body_size 11m;

     gzip on;
     gzip_types text/plain application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml text/css;

     error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
     access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;


     root /var/www/html;

     location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        autoindex on;
      }
```

Just copy/pasted the part of my website conf serving the actual site files.

Comment: Rather than using `https://sub.domain.com.s3-xxxxxxx.com`, would you be willing to use `https://s3-xxxxxxx.com/sub.domain.com/`? This way, it will use the S3 certificate. If this is not acceptable, then your only way to use a custom domain name with SSL is to go via Amazon CloudFront.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It wasn't acceptable indeed.
Anyway the reason of my error was quite logical. Certbot can't create .well-known directory on a s3-bucket.

I ended up making my NGINX conf file point to one of my sites in order to generate certificates, and then modify it to point to my bucket ...

It's a really dirty solution and I would advise anyone to use the aformentionned CloudFront solution.

Comment: A point of clarification: you are not trying to redirect `https://sub.domain.com` to `https://sub.domain.com.s3-xxxxxxx.com` you are actually trying to *proxy*  `https://sub.domain.com` to `https://sub.domain.com.s3-xxxxxxx.com`. Also, is there any reason you are trying to do this through an EC2 instance running Nginx, instead of using CloudFront?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to just make sub.domain.com to resolve to your ec2 ip? ( no redirection, it should just resolve with either A or CNAME to your ec2 instance)
If yes, we can have nginx conf to redirect sub.domain.conf/* to your s3 bucket and serve file from local read write volume if location is sub.domain.com/.well-known/* so that certbot can generate certificate as well. BTW, how are you generating cert for your S3 bucket ?
Hope this helps, thanks !